# Xcode 5.1 Code Coverage File Generation Inaccurate

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, code-coverage

I am attempting to use [XcodeCoverage](https://github.com/jonreid/XcodeCoverage) to get code coverage reports but am finding that lines that I know are being executed are not showing in the coverage reports or the raw gcov files. I followed the XcodeCoverage installation guide in multiple projects and am seeing the same results.

I created a [sample project](https://github.com/cwagdev/CoverageTesting) that exhibits the same behavior, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: how about [coverstory](https://code.google.com/p/coverstory/)?

Comment: I'm not too worried about the "wrapper", it seems to be a problem at the Code Generation level that LLVM should be handling. I've used CoverStory in the past prior to iOS 7. I will give their guide a shot and report back.

Comment: I tried following the cover story guide with no luck, created a new branch that as the GTMCoverage stuff, https://github.com/cwagdev/CoverageTesting/tree/coverstory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many different things, the answer was to not include the main target's classes in the test target's "Target Membership".

[image]